# Use systemd-run to schedule command after reboot

Tags: systemd, scheduled-task

I need to schedule a command to run at a certain time in the future. `systemd-run` with the `--on-calendar` option seems like it can do that, except that it seems the service is only stored ephemerally and is lost if the host reboots. And in this case the host will certainly reboot before I need to the command to run.

I know I could manually write service and timer files, but that is a little less convenient than using `systemd-run` for a one-off task, and I need to go back and clean up the service files aftewards. Is there a way to tell `systemd-run` to persist the job across reboots?

Answer (score 0):

No. Transient units in tmpfs at `/run/systemd/transient/` don't survive reboots.

Timer units with OnCalendar conditions can be put in persistent locations like `/etc/systemd/system/`

Outside of systemd's domain, atd will run a thing at a time, and clean up its spool when done.